# Test tensorflow-gpu failed with Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version (which is not true)

Tags: linux, drivers, python, gpu, cuda

I have the following configuration:

- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3  (x86_64)
- CUDA Toolkit: CUDA 9.2 (9.2.148 Update 1)
- CUDA Driver Version: 396.37

According to NVIDIA just right (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#major-components).

I set up a new environment with Anaconda and installed tensorflow-gpu in it:

```
conda create -n keras python=3.6.8 anaconda
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

But if I then want to check the installation via *python* console:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

I get the following error:

> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.753926: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use:
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.793109: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
>   2600180000 Hz
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.798218: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service
>   0x561f42601240 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.798258: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): ,
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.981727: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service
>   0x561f426ad9b0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.981777: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): Tesla K40c, Compute Capability 3.5
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.982175: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0
>   with properties:
>
> name: Tesla K40c major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.745
>   pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.09GiB
>
> 2019-04-17 15:23:45.982206: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/fuchs/.conda/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1551, in **init**
>       super(Session, self).**init**(target, graph, config=config)   File "/home/fuchs/.conda/envs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 676, in **init**
>       self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:
>   cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient
>   for CUDA runtime version

I've been looking for solutions from others with this problem, but for most of them it was because the CUDA Toolkit and Driver version didn't match. Which is not the case with me.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I've already found the solution myself. My mistake was that I created the Anaconda environment with a *python* version >3.5. Under these circumstances tensorflow-gpu=1.13 will be installed, if you execute the following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

However, if you create an environment with python=3.5, tensorflow-gpu=1.10 will be installed, which works for this CUDA version.